# Lemma $1.4.3$ from "Algebra and Geometry" by A. F. Beardon

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I am trying to understand the following statement:

> Suppose that the identity permutation $I$ on $\{1,2, \dots,n \}$ can be expressed as a product of $m$ transpositions. Then $m$ is even.

The definition of transposition: a $2$-cycle $(r,s)$ which interchanges the distinct integers $r$ and $s$ and leaves all other integers fixed.

Now the author proves this with induction on $n$, however, it is trivial that $m=0$ no matter what $n$ is. Because, there is no $2$-cycle representation for identity permutation. Am I correct to jump this conclusion or missing something important? Many thanks!

Comment: Think of what happens when I transpose r and s and then do the same transposition again

Comment: For a hint to the solution, you may want to look at the signature of the identity, and that of a transposition